# XLSX file saved as CSV leads to date format issues when we open the saved CSV file (XLSX "save as" CSV)

Tags: excel

I am creating a CSV file from an XLSX FILE /  CSV file meant for import into another application ....  say Foxpro

I have tried my level best to convert Date in Column A with DD-MM-YYYY,  using =TEXT(A1,"DD/MM/YY"), and all possible ways, However, if I save this to CSV Format and try to open the same, I find the first 12 days in DD-MM-YYYY ...(12-12-1965) form  .....and the rest of it till 30th day, exactly the way I want it, like (12/13/1965.....  and so on ...

Why do the first 12 days lead to a hyphenated date,  instead of the "/" SLASH that I used in the =text() formula in Excel?   subsequent dates (from the 13th day)  are correctly displayed as 12/13/1965,  12/13/1965, and so on). When I try to import this CSV file into FoxPro,  it leads to blank dates for the slashed dates viz., 12/14/1965, ...  and so on...

I seek help to get rid of that Hyphens ... The formula bar CLEARLY displays the hyphen EVEN THOUGH THE VALUE IN THE CELL IS DISPLAYING "/" Slash... This causes import/data porting to lead to blanks as stated above...  Unless the formula bar displays it as dd/mm/yyyy, I cant import it...

can someone help, please

Comment: My experience is that when you load a CSV into Excel, anything that looks like a date, gets interpreted as a date. For me, the data was UK bank account sort codes - `20-09-68` would become `20/Sep/1968`, while `20-13-68` would remain text. I didn't find a solution except to convert the date values back to text with a formula.

Comment: Before continuing, could you make sure you switch the date format to YYYY-MM-DD? That format will save you a lot of troubles with export/import, it is also standardized international format, so for data processing, do not use local exotic formats any more. As the second step, could you attempt to copy the entire sheet into clipboard and save it to plain text as .tsv file? (tab-separated values) Your target database should support it besides the CSV.

Comment: **IMPORT** the csv file using either the legacy wizard or Power Query. Then you will be able to tell Excel the format of the date in the incoming file and it will interpret it the way it should.  When you **OPEN** a csv file, Excel will interpret the date in accord with your regional windows settings, and this can lead to problems.  As suggested by @miroxlav, using `yyyy-mm-dd` format may help with dates (but won't with other entries that might look like dates).

Comment: I AM GRATEFUL TO ALL THREE OF YOU WHO HAVE RESPONDED IN A WINK...  I NEVER EXPECTED THIS QUICK, A REPLY FROM YOU ALL....  AND THAT TOO FOR TRYING TO HELP ME OVER FOXPRO, WHICH IS USED BY A SMALLER COMMUNITY...  I AM THANKFUL TO ALL THREE OF YOU ....   THE ISSUE OF HYPHEN KEPT CREEPING...  I HAD TO GET IT AS A DOT-TXT FILE ...  SOMEWHAT IN LINES OF OUR FRIEND MIROXLAV...  AND HAD TO USE THE CTOD( ) FUNCTION OVER THE STRING mm-dd-yyyy TO PORT THE VALUES....  ONCE AGAIN THANKS TO ALL YOU GUYS...  I AM HAPPY THAT YOU GAVE YOUR TWO CENTS...   THANKS AGAIN....